# Alter table modify column query results in SQL Syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql

I get this error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: 
>       Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
>       syntax to use near 
>       '(`sfname2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `slname2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , ' at line 2'

When I try to run this query:

```
$stmnt = $db->prepare('ALTER TABLE eventfields MODIFY  
                       (sfname2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
                       slname2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
                       ....
                       customfield1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,)');
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the parenthesis around your columns and you need `MODIFY COLUMN` for each column being altered.

```
$stmnt = $db->prepare('ALTER TABLE eventfields   
                   MODIFY COLUMN sfname2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
                   MODIFY COLUMN slname2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
                   ....
                   MODIFY COLUMN customfield1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ');
```

Comment: Oh. I still get an error. Now its near `'slname2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , school2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , gr' at line 3'`

Comment: ok. Is it possible to do `NOT NULL DEFAULT 'something'` in one query or does setting the default have to be in another one?

Comment: So now I am getting `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2030 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet` on `(65): PDOStatement->execute()`

Comment: had to do $db->exec(..) instead of prepare.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error on a MODIFY COLUMN after a MySQL upgrade:
`check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups MODIFY COLUMN description TEXT'`

Turns out my table/column names were newly added as MySQL reserved words, so I just had to add my backticks:

`` ALTER TABLE `groups` MODIFY COLUMN `description` TEXT ``

I realize this is not the exact same issue as the OP, but the error message initially let me to believe it was related to the MODIFY COLUMN, and this was the first SO match I found.